# Is $e^x$ the only isomorphism between the groups $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{> 0},*)$?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

If so, how might I be able to prove it?

EDIT: OK, thanks to many answers especially spin's and Micah's explanations. All of the answers were extremely helpful in understanding -- I have accepted Micah's because it seems the most complete, but all answers provide helpful additions/perspectives! I have tried to summarize:

> $\phi$ is an isomorphism between the groups if and only if $\phi(x) = e^{f(x)}$ where $f$ is an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ back to $(\mathbb{R},+)$.

Of course there are lots of such $f$, especially when we take the Axiom of Choice.

However, it seems from the answers and Micah's link ([Cauchy functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)) that the only "nice" solutions are $f(x) = cx$ for a constant $c$. It seems that all others must be "highly pathological" (in fact $\{(x,f(x))\}$ must be dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

A remaining question is, how strong is the statement

> All such isomorphisms have the form $e^{cx}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$

or its negation? Or what is required for each to hold?

One answer seems to be that supposing the reals have the [Baire property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire) is sufficient to rule out other solutions (as is assuming every subset of the reals is measurable, assuming the [Axiom of Determinacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy), and it holds in [Solovay's model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model)). For more, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166176/a-question-concerning-on-the-axiom-of-choice-and-cauchy-functional-equation), [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110125/is-there-a-non-trivial-example-of-a-mathbb-q-endomorphism-of-mathbb-r), and [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57426/are-there-any-non-linear-solutions-of-cauchys-equation-fxyfxfy-with).

Comment: well you could aslo have $e^{nx}$ for positive $n$. Or $a^nx$.

Comment: Ah, good point. I think the question is still interesting when we exclude that case though!

Comment: As I just added, it also works for any number positive number instead of $e$. Still interesting excluding that though :(

Comment: See @GEdgar's comment below.

Comment: I think the negation of the last one is only a consequence, because it is a statement about the subsets of $\mathbb R$. It cannot imply statements about arbitrary sets.... It follows from the fact that $\mathbb R$ has a $\mathbb Q$-basis.

Comment: @N.S. oh, I see, thank you. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ be an isomorphism. Then $g=\log f$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$: that is, it satisfies
$$
g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y) \, .
$$
This is [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). The only continuous (or even measurable) solutions are the trivial ones (which correspond to $f(x)=e^{cx}$), but there are also exotic solutions that require some version of the axiom of choice to construct — which would yield similarly exotic $f$s.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! My question now (last question?) is how "strong" is the axiom that such solutions exist, or the axiom that they don't?

Comment: @usul: I'm sorry, I'm not enough of a set theorist to give a good answer to that question. (Though many people here are; you'd probably get good answers if you asked it as a separate question!)

Comment: no problem, a search turned up several relevant threads and I have linked to them in my edited question!

Answer (score 10):

Once you have an isomorphism, there are plenty. Take two [Hamel bases](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamelBasis.html) of $\mathbf{R}$, say $(b_i)$ and $(c_i)$, and define $f$ by
$$
f(b_i) = e^{c_i},
$$ 
extending it by $\mathbf{Q}$-linearity to all of $\mathbf{R}$.

**PS** Of course I am implicitly using here the argument of @Micah and @spin.

Comment: And this is where the axiom of choice comes in.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, precisely!

Answer (score 6):

$e^{2x}$ is another one. In general if $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a group isomorphism, then $e^{\phi(x)}$ is another one.

---

One should also note that if $\phi$ is a group isomorphism between $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_{>0},*)$, then $\log(\phi)$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R},+)$. Now the question is to determine the group automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ as a group under addition

Comment: And (by Axiom of Choice) there are discontinuous homomorphisms.

Comment: @GEdgar and therefore isomorphisms, right?

Comment: @Amr: Every isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is of the form $e^{\phi(x)}$, see my answer

Comment: @GEdgar I think that I heard before that there are discontinuous homomorphisms(I didnt see the construction though). Are there discontinuous isomorphisms ?

Comment: @Amr I think the answer is given by Micah's link? [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)

Comment: And thank you for the response! Very helpful. I have tried to summarize above some answers to your question that I found by searching.

Answer (score 6):

$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+} \text{ satisfying } f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, $f$ continuous, then $f(x)=e^{cx}$

Try to solve this problem Any Lie Group Homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ is of the form $e^{iax}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and every such homomorphism is smooth.

Comment: (+1). Any ideas if $f$ is discontinous?

Comment: Does it really have to be $e$? Why not $a>0$.

Comment: Any Lie group Homomorphism is smooth

Comment: @Joe Tait $\forall a>0 \exists c\in\mathbb{R} [a=e^c]$

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $G \cong H$ as groups and that $f: G \rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism. Then every isomorphism $G \rightarrow H$ is of the form $f \circ g$, where $g: G \rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism. So to determine every isomorphism $G \rightarrow H$, it suffices to find just one and then the rest are given by composing with automorphisms of $G$.

Because $x \mapsto e^x$ is an isomorphism $(\mathbb{R}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \cdot)$, every isomorphism $(\mathbb{R}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}_{>0}, \cdot)$ is of the form $x \mapsto e^{\varphi(x)}$, where $\varphi$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, +)$.

Comment: Dear spin, many thanks for your nice answer!

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful/clear!